# How to avoid Line breaks in the Result set (in attachment) sent using SP_SEND_DBMAIL

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

```
EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
@PROFILE_NAME = 'NoReply Mail'
, @RECIPIENTS = 'chandra@gmail.com'
, @BODY_FORMAT ='HTML'
, @BODY = @body
, @SUBJECT = @subject
, @QUERY = @SQL
, @ATTACH_QUERY_RESULT_AS_FILE = 1
, @QUERY_ATTACHMENT_FILENAME = @query_filename
, @QUERY_RESULT_SEPARATOR = '   '
, @QUERY_RESULT_NO_PADDING = 1
, @EXCLUDE_QUERY_OUTPUT = 1
, @APPEND_QUERY_ERROR = 0
, @QUERY_RESULT_HEADER = 0
```

**When I get an attachment, I see line breaks in the data (i.e. data in one row displaying in the second row as well of the excel attachment. How can I avoid that? Thanks in advance. **

Comment: I got the solution. Need to use REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') in select query. Thanks!

Comment: It is so hard to test coz we don't have like your own.